# why C++ can't free memory and pointer simultaneously

Tags: c++, pointers, dma

I have learned that in C++(download form VSCode 0.26.3) although a memory have already been freed, the pointers pointed to it won't change, which means they won't be NULL.

Is there any method can let the pointer be NULL?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Use a smart pointer. E.g. `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`, depending on the use-case. There the pointer will do memory management and you can do both at once (e.g. by calling `reset()`).

Comment: Your programs logic should "know" what pointers hold valid pointer values and which ones don't. Setting a pointer to `nullptr` for that purpose smells.

Comment: Personally, I avoid using raw pointers at all - by using a smart pointer, or a standard container.   If I must use a raw pointer, instead of setting it to NULL after releasing whatever it points at, I ensure the pointer itself ceases to exist - for example, due to passing out of scope, or (if it is contained in an object) because the containing object ceases to exist.    If you have to set a pointer to NULL, it means you have kept the pointer itself around longer than needed.

Comment: @J.Doe nullptr checking pointers is totally fine. Even if you want to assert their validity, they still need to be nullptr for that to work reliably. If anything the only reason not to null out a free'd pointer is if the pointer itself is about to be destroyed or reassigned.

Comment: @George `[ ]` You did understand my comment.

Comment: I mean, let's think about how this would have to work. You'd either need for each accessible spot a list of pointers that point towards it, or you'd need to iterate through all pointers to see if they point towards that spot. See how this is not a feasible thing to do? If you really use raw pointers more than tightly within some wrapper (like a custom array class), then go for strong concepts of ownership. That is, have it either pointing downwards in a relationship, or only within a small scope in which the actual owner is bound not to die.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is no method to do this automatically and it is important to realize that also setting the pointer to `nullptr` manually wont solve the general problem. To see why, consider this simplified example:

```
int* x = new int(5);
int* y = x;
delete x;
x = nullptr;
if (x) // attempt to check if x still points to an object
    std::cout << *x;
if (y) // attempt to check if y still points to an object
    std::cout << *y;  // !! UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR !!
```

It is common to see pointers being set to `nullptr` after the call to `delete`. However, imagine `y` is not in the same scope as `x` but some other object holds `y`, then there is no way that other object "knows" that `y` is no longer a valid pointer.

To avoid this and other problems [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) have beeen introduced and raw pointers should be avoided.

Comment: `raw pointers should be avoided`. **owning** raw pointer should be avoided, but as long as `observer_ptr` is not part of the standard there are still many valid places to use raw pointers at.

Comment: @t.niese I had "owning raw pointers" first but then realized that I would have to explain more, because in the example `y` is the problem and `y` is not the owning pointer. Instead adding more explanation I allowed myself some sloppyness. In this scenario it should perhaps be shared and weak pointer, so I think it is fine to rule out raw pointers and leave them to the "informed" reader

Comment: @t.niese in general I agree that "dont use raw pointers" is unnecessary (or even harmful) exaggeration, but on the other hand "avoid raw pointers" does not exclude to use them in cases where they are appropriate (but not not in others)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using raw pointer then whenever you release memory assign pointer to NULL explicitly. There is no automatic way for raw pointers.