# How to delete a pointer in C++ properly?

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor

I'm new to C++ and I have a question.

Lets assume you declared the variable `x` using the following code:

```
MyClass *x = new MyClass();
```

After using this variable, I no longer need it.

Among the following propositions, what would then be the preferred course of action and what's the difference?

1. Call `free(x);`
2. Call `x->~MyClass();`
3. Call `MyClass::~MyClass(p);`
4. Call `delete x;`

Can someone help me to understand this?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Variable create with `new` should be deleted with `delete`

Comment: the prefered course of action is to not write `MyClass *x = new MyClass();` in the first place, but `MyClass x;` or use a smart-pointer if you really need to dynamically allocate

Comment: Please use std::make_unique<T> as default way of creating pointers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly free the memory allocated by placement new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918791/how-to-properly-free-the-memory-allocated-by-placement-new)

Comment: You don't use `new` at all. Instead use `std::unique_ptr<T> var = std::make_unique<T>();`

Comment: @RamblinRose thats not a duplicate, it is about placement new

Comment: This should be of use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 6):

**If** you create an instance via `new` :

```
MyClass *x = new MyClass();
```

you **must** delete it via `delete`:

```
delete x;
```

> 1.) Call `free(x);`

No. `free` only releases memory it does not call destructors. If you `malloc` memory you need to `free` it, but it is rare that you have to use `malloc` in C++ and calling `free` on a pointer obtained from `new` is wrong.

> 2.) Call `x->~MyClass();`

No. Explicitly calling the destructor is almost always wrong!

(For example when you create an object via placement new then you don't call `delete` but the destructor directly, because placement new creates the object in already allocated memory.)

> 3.) Call `MyClass::~MyClass(p);`

No. This makes no sense, destructors take no parameters.

> 4.) Call `delete x;`

Yes. [Calling `delete`...](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete)

> Destroys object(s) previously allocated by the new expression **and** releases obtained memory area

**But** you should not manually manage memory. Either rely on automatic storage:

```
MyClass x;
```

The detructor of `x` is called automatically when it goes out of scope. Or if you really need dynamic memory allocation use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers).

For further reading: [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)
By the way, this is such a common misconception that each talk of Stroustrup i remember has an example that uses `new` to create an object and then he explains that it should definitely not use `new`. Actually there is more to it than forgetting to call `delete`. Consider:

```
 { 
     MyClass *x = new MyClass();
     foo();   
     delete x;   // phew I didnt forget to call delete
 }
```

If `foo` throws an exception then this code leaks memory. The right way is to rely on RAII:

```
 { 
     MyClass x;
     foo();   
 }
```

Now if `foo` throws an exception, the destructor of `x` will be called!

Comment: I agree with the delete part. Next to that, within my company it is practice to always let this pointer point to 0, e.g. ```delete x; x = 0;```

Comment: @dejoma coincidentally I answered a question about that just recently. Setting the pointer to `nullptr` has a (limited) use, but its main effect is a false sense of security. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60522321/4117728 . It does not solve the general problem that comes with using `new` and `delete` manually

Comment: *Next to that, within my company it is practice to always let this pointer point to 0* -- There is only one reason I know of why this has any effect -- A 0-pointer indicates that the object needs to be allocated.  If it's used like this: `if (ptr != nullptr) delete ptr;` the check for nullptr can be entirely removed, since deleting a nullptr is perfectly valid.  If it's used because your program flow takes so many twists and turns that you don't know the state of your pointer, then the code probably needs to be reviewed.

Comment: "*If you create an instance via `new` ... you must delete it via `delete`*" - except when you use `placement-new`, then don't use `delete` at all, you must call the type's destructor directly ala #2 instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks, added a note. I think the "If ... you must" is still fine because it refers to OPs code

Answer (score 4):

Variable dynamically allocated with the `new` keyword should be deleted by using the `delete` keyword. `new` and `delete` **call the constructor and the destructor** of the specified class. This means your instance is initalized and deinitialized properly.

So, instance `x` initialized with `MyClass *x = new MyClass();` should be deleted with `delete x;`.

However, it is always better, if possible, to declare variable on stack like `MyClass x;` and let [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) do its work. Take a look at the following example:

```cpp
{
    // creates an object 'x' on stack
    MyClass x;

    // do something with 'x'

    // once the object is out of scope, it is automatically being destructed
}
```

Furthermore, if you still need dynamic allocation, modern C++ suggests using smart pointers, like [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). Smart pointers automatically take care of memory handling instead of you. In other words, by using smart pointers, you don't need to care about `delete`ing the object created with the `new`. You can write something like:

```cpp
{
    // creates an object 'x' on heap
    // its default ctor is being called
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> x = std::make_shared<MyClass>();

    // once the object is out of scope, even though it is allocated
    // on the heap, there is no need to call 'delete' here because
    // deletion is automatically handled by the 'std::shared_ptr'
}
```

Comment: note that the important point of RAII is that `x` is destroyed no matter what, also when there is an excpetion (or `return`), if the scope would be left always at `}` then actually using `new` and `delete` wouldn't be that critical. Just realized that your "//once the object is out of scope" suggests that you always leave the scope at `}`, because I ended up with a similar example to yours. Anyhow you have my +1,

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes, thanks for pointing that out. Anyway, you have my +1 too.